# Pandas - join with missing columns as NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Imagine two dataframes:

```
X = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], columns=["a", "b"])
Y = pd.DataFrame([10,20,30], columns=["a"])

>>> X
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6
>>> Y
   a
0  10
1  20
2  30
```

Overall, I want my final output to be like this:

```
   a_X  b_X  a_Y b_Y sum_a sum_b
0    1  2    10  NaN  11      2
1    3  4    20  NaN  23      4
2    5  6    30  NaN  35      6
```

I tried to do it by:

```
merged = X.join(Y, lsuffix="_X", rsuffix="_Y")
merged['sum_a'] = merged['a_X'] + merged['a_Y'] # works
merged['sum_b'] = merged['b_X'] + merged['b_Y'] # doesn't work
```

Obviously the sum_b column will fail because there was no b column in the Y set. It could be there, but it doesn't have to, my dataset doesn't have any guarantees. It doesn't look like I can use built-in join to add that "NaN" column there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate with `pd.concat` -

```
k = ['X', 'Y']

df = pd.concat([X, Y], keys=k, axis=1)
df

   X      Y
   a  b   a
0  1  2  10
1  3  4  20
2  5  6  30
```

Generate a MultiIndex and use it to reindex -

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([k, df.columns.levels[1].unique()])
df = df.reindex(columns=idx)
df

   X      Y    
   a  b   a   b
0  1  2  10 NaN
1  3  4  20 NaN
2  5  6  30 NaN
```

Re-set the column names -

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
df

   X_a  X_b  Y_a  Y_b
0    1    2   10  NaN
1    3    4   20  NaN
2    5    6   30  NaN
```

Now, you can groupby suffix and find sums -

```
v = df.groupby(by=lambda x: x.split('_')[1], axis=1).sum().add_prefix('sum_')
v

   sum_a  sum_b
0   11.0    2.0
1   23.0    4.0
2   35.0    6.0
```

Concatenate this with the original:

```
pd.concat([df, v], 1)

   X_a  X_b  Y_a  Y_b  sum_a  sum_b
0    1    2   10  NaN   11.0    2.0
1    3    4   20  NaN   23.0    4.0
2    5    6   30  NaN   35.0    6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df=pd.concat([X,Y.reindex(columns=X.columns)],keys=['x','y'],axis=1)

x=df.groupby(level=1,axis=1).sum().add_prefix('sum_')

df.columns=df.columns.map('{0[1]}{0[0]}'.format)


pd.concat([df,x],1)
Out[58]: 
   ax  bx  ay  by  sum_a  sum_b
0   1   2  10 NaN   11.0    2.0
1   3   4  20 NaN   23.0    4.0
2   5   6  30 NaN   35.0    6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
import numpy as np

Y['b'] = np.nan
merged = X.join(Y, lsuffix="_X", rsuffix="_Y")
merged['sum_a'] = merged['a_X'] + merged['a_Y']
merged['sum_b'] = merged['b_X'] + merged.fillna(0)['b_Y']

#>>> merged
#   a_X  b_X  a_Y  b_Y  sum_a  sum_b
#0    1    2   10  NaN     11    2.0
#1    3    4   20  NaN     23    4.0
#2    5    6   30  NaN     35    6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative closer to what you are doing. As `Y` does not have to have the same columns as `X` you can use `reindex` for `Y` and then perform the operations with the `fill_value` option:

```
Y = Y.reindex(columns=X.columns)
>>> Y
#    a    b
#0  10  NaN
#1  20  NaN  
#2  30  NaN

merged = X.join(Y, lsuffix="_X", rsuffix="_Y")
merged['sum_a'] = merged['a_X'].add(merged['a_Y'], fill_value=0)
merged['sum_b'] = merged['b_X'].add(merged['b_Y'], fill_value=0)
```